# Selecting entire word that includes dashes

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the string

```
hello how-ar[]e-you doing
```

where `[]` is my cursor. How would I efficiently select `how-are-you` such that

```
hello [how-are-you] doing
```

So far what I could come up with is `Bvt<space>`

Comment: `vaW`, sort of (includes the following space).

Comment: `viW` would select only the word, without spaces

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Vim has the notion of "word" and "WORD", where a "word" is a sequence of characters in the `'iskeyword'` option and a "WORD" is a sequence of non-whitespace characters.

Thus…

- the `w` motion ("word") would jump to the `-` after `are` because `-` is not part of `'iskeyword'`,
- the `W` motion ("WORD") would jump to `doing`,
- the `iw` text-object ("inner word") would cover `are`,
- the `iW` text-object ("inner WORD") would cover `how-are-you`,
- and so on for other motions and text-objects.

What you are looking for is the `iW` text-object:

```
viW
```

`:help navigation` will blow your mind.

Comment: How can you do this in Xcode? By default Xcode treats dashes as word boundaries, so you can't auto select variables-with-dashes-in-their-names. Xcode does this for both Swift and Objective-C, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: I don't know I've never used XCode. You should write a question with the XCode tag to find out.

Answer (score 15):

besides the other answers (using Word instead of word) if you want this to be the default behaviour (such that `-` will be considered a word character - not a word delimiter) you may add this to your vimrc

```
set iskeyword+="-"
```

after that `viw` will give you the expected result. 
type `:h iskeyword` for more info about it

Comment: This didn't work for me without removing the quotes: `set iskeyword+=-`.

Additionally, you can use https://github.com/machakann/vim-textobj-delimited to maintain the ability target individual words.

Comment: This is great because it also extends to `C-N`